# "there grew a feeling"

Tags: word-usage

[There are 837 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22there%20grew%20a%20feeling%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) in Google Books that use "there grew a feeling".

Learning those, I made up this:

> Last year I seldom go home because of work, there grew a feeling that I didn't care about my family.

Is it the correct use? How do I convey my wife had that feeling?

Comment: There's more of a problem with "Last year I seldom go home". "go" is present tense, but you're talking about the past.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may notice that the uses of "there grew a feeling" at your link are referring to widespread changes in sentiment, shared by many people. The "growing" isn't an increase in the feeling in an individual, but rather that it is spreading to more and more people. I don't think the phrase fits as well when describing a change of sentiment in an individual. Your example sentence would be more natural as

> "Last year, because of work, I seldom went home, and my wife started to feel that I didn't care about my family."